# Getting gps coordinates without a gps module

Tags: gps

I am working on Raspberry PI B+.
I have to get the current location of the system in python.
Is there a way to do that without using a GPS Module ?

The PI is always connected to the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [GeoIP2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2).
It won't work like a GPS but depending on the purpose, might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Wifi network adaptor connected, you can query Google's geocoding API with the access point data to get location.

The following command line will retrieve the location:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | sed -E '1s/.*/{"wifiAccessPoints":[/;s/^ *Cell.*: (.*)/{"macAddress":"\1",/;s/^ *Channel:(.*)/"channel":\1,/;s/^.*nal level=(-[0-9]+) .*/"signalStrength":\1},/;/^ /d;$d' | sed '$s/.$/]}/' | curl -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=${APIKEY}"
```

You'll need to set the `APIKEY` environment variable. You can get an API key from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key.

Answer (score 0):

curl https://ipvigilante.com, this is the best you can do.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the application, but this is close enough to freak me out.

[html5_geolocation_watchposition](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_watchposition)

Click the button to *Try it*; *Share* you location with **w3schools.com**; Modify the script in the other panel of the webpage to suit.

Edit: Sorry, just noticed the "in Python" but will leave it up.